# Select rectangle interactively and obtain corner coods opencv

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I am trying to realize the grabcut segmentation, with the functions available in opencv and the implementation from [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_grabcut/py_grabcut.html).

In the code . same as shown here

```
     import numpy as np
     import cv2
     from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

     img = cv2.imread('messi5.jpg')
     mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2],np.uint8)

     bgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)
     fgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)

     rect = (50,50,450,290)
     cv2.grabCut(img,mask,rect,bgdModel,fgdModel,5,cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)

     mask2 = np.where((mask==2)|(mask==0),0,1).astype('uint8')
     img = img*mask2[:,:,np.newaxis]

     plt.imshow(img),plt.colorbar(),plt.show()
```

However, as you can see in the code, the rectangle coordinates are hard coded. I want to interactively select a rectangle, by displaying the input image and use the corner coods of that rectangle for further processing. Am pretty new to both python and opencv. I am tryying here, but your help is much needed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kAwxLTDDAwU, https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/python2/grabcut.py

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_table_of_contents_gui/py_table_of_contents_gui.html#py-table-of-content-gui